# Icon tab bar in Sapui5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using `IconTabBar` in my project. IconTabFilters calling from fragments. When user click a button in fragment, the selected IconTabFilter will be active. How can I do this?

This my `master.view.xml` part:

```
<IconTabFilter key="home" icon="sap-icon://home" iconColor="Neutral" text="home">
                    <core:Fragment fragmentName="App.view.second" type="XML" />
                    </IconTabFilter>
```

This my fragment content:

```
<Button text="Continue" type="Accept" press="pressCont" id="pressCont" ></Button>
```

Comment: What does active mean? Do you have more than one IconTabFilters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This icon tab bar has 2 icon tab filter in master.view.xml.

```
<IconTabFilter key="homeFl"  iconColor="Neutral" text="home">
<core:Fragment fragmentName="App.view.home" type="XML" />
</IconTabFilter>
<IconTabFilter key="personelFl"  iconColor="Neutral" text="PersonelFl"  >
<core:Fragment fragmentName="App.view.personel" type="XML" />
</IconTabFilter>
```

When user click this button in my home fragment, personel fragment will be active with this code. This part in master.controller.

```
 pressCont:function(evt){

   var oPanelMenu1 = this.byId("idIconTabBarSeparatorIcon");// get icon tab bar

   oPanelMenu1.setSelectedKey("personelFl");//set active filter with predefined key
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Case I:** Assuming that you have more than one `IconTabFilter`,

there is no property called **active/inactive**, nevertheless you can use/control the **visibility** of the `IconTabFilter` OR `IconTabBar` itself.

Use `oIconTabFilter.setVisible(true);` // Read more [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.IconTabFilter.html#setVisible)

**Case II:** Assuming that you have one `IconTabFilter` and multiple `IconTabBar`s

There is a method called `setSelectedKey`Read more [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.IconTabBar.html#setSelectedKey)

```
oIconTabBar.setSelectedKey(true);
```

Comment: thank you so much. ı tried debug and find views and other things but only id solved my problem:).